# My Laptops internal mic is not Detected

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, audio, amd

I have tried the gnome version of both Fedora 38 and ubuntu 23.04 on my Acer Aspire 315-24p laptop with AMD Ryzen 5 7520u processor. Non of the OSes detect my  laptops internal mic. My mic is nowhere listed . I am running Kernel 6.6rc. Please help

Comment: Please provide the output of arecord -l (minus L)

Comment: @MC68020  here is it : **** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 2: ALC256 Alt Analog [ALC256 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 2/2
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1